# iOS safari not showing all options for select menu

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I have a select menu on a website that I'm in the process of making mobile friendly and it works perfectly on desktop and on chrome for iOS, but on safari for iOS it shows only the selected option. It will scroll through and can select the other options, but they are invisible.

Below are images of the issue:

[image: iOS safari]
[image: iOS safari]

And this is what it should look like as it is displayed in chrome for iOS:

[image: iOS chrome]

The issue seems to lie with this script I am using to resize and re-align the select menu depending on which option is selected.

```
<script>
var resized = false;

function resizeSelect(selected) {
if (resized) return;
var sel = document.getElementById('category');
for (var i=0; i<sel.options.length; i++) {
sel.options[i].title=sel.options[i].innerHTML;
if (i!=sel.options.selectedIndex) sel.options[i].innerHTML='';
}
resized = true;
sel.blur();
}

function restoreSelect() {
if (!resized) return;
var sel = document.getElementById('category');
for (var i=0; i<sel.options.length; i++) {
sel.options[i].innerHTML=sel.options[i].title;
}  
resized = false;
}
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<form id="sortfilter" method="post" action="">
<select id="category" class="styled-select" name="category"  onchange="resizeSelect(this.selectedItem), form.submit()" onblur="resizeSelect(this.selectedItem)" onfocus="restoreSelect()">
<option value="All" selected>All</option>
<option value="Apparel">Apparel</option>
<option value="Boats">Boats</option>
<option value="Cars">Cars</option>
<option value="Food + Drink">Food + Drink</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Any thoughts as to what the problem may be and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: For some reason I am now also having this same problem with chrome for iOS... Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible your JS is or CSS is affecting it in an unexpected way? Based on @cjungel 's answer and the fact that you can still scroll through the selector, it seems like your HTML is probably fine.

Answer (score 24):

I had the same issue on specific versions of Safari on iOS.

The following html causes the picker not to display the option labels in iOS.

```
<select>
  <option value="1" label="one"/>
  <option value="2" label="two"/>
  <option value="3" label="three"/>
</select>
```

When I rewrote the same html in the following way was correctly displayed.

```
<select>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You saved my life yesterday. That is the correct answer

Comment: It seems like Safari on iOS doesn't display the value of the label attribute on option tags at all. Not sure why - MDN shows it should have full support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this today. As per the compatibility tables I could find, dynamically setting the `label` attribute would be enough for all iOS versions to display the control label. Turns out this depends on the iOS version.

Apparently you got away with not setting `innerText` on iOS 7-9, but iOS 10 and up requires `innerText` to be set for the label to display.

#### iOS 10+

```
let option = document.createElement('option');
// option.innerText required on iOS 10 and up.
option.label = option.innerText = 'My option label';
option.value = '123';
```

#### iOS 7-9

```
var option = document.createElement('option');
// option.innerText not required on iOS 7-9.
option.label = 'My option label';
option.value = '123';
```

Please note of course that the `let` keyword was not available prior to iOS 10.